# How to read objective-c stack traces

Tags: iphone, objective-c, stack-trace

i have the following stack trace:

```
0 MyApp 0x000833a3 +[TFCrashHandler backtrace] + 26
1 MyApp 0x000836bd TFSignalHandler + 28
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x33eac727 _sigtramp + 34
3 ??? 0x00000002 0x0 + 2
4 MyApp 0x000803f1 msgpack_unpack_next + 112
5 MyApp 0x0007faeb +[MessagePackParser parseData:] + 74
6 MyApp 0x0007f84b -[NSData(NSData_MessagePack) messagePackParse] + 26
7 MyApp 0x000254c3 +[Http get:params:cacheMins:msgPack:complete:] + 146
...
```

And i'm wondering how to read it:

- I assume i go from the bottom up, eg line 7 called line 6 called line 5, etc.
- What does the '+ 112' on line 4 mean? Is that a line number in the code file where it crashed?
- What does the '???' on line 3 mean?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does the '0x00000002' mean that the msgpack_unpack_next function jumped to a function at address '2', eg did an invalid function call somehow?

Comment: Nope;  it is just a bogon stack frame likely as a result from compiler optimization.  Best to ignore.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
0 MyApp 0x000833a3 +[TFCrashHandler backtrace] + 26
```

Crash was generated from `+[TFCrashHandler backtrace]` + 26;  from whatever instruction fell at that symbol location + 26 bytes.

If that is really the bottom of your stack trace and it crashed there, then the `TCrashHandler` is obscuring the real crash.   The real crash looks to be a couple of frames above.

```
1 MyApp 0x000836bd TFSignalHandler + 28
```

TFSignalHandler was what called +backtrace.

```
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x33eac727 _sigtramp + 34
```

Ewww... a signal trampoline.  The app  received a signal and the a trampoline was set to call TFSignalHandler().

There are situations where a signal handler might be called on a random thread.  I.e. there is a minuscule chance that this particular crash had nothing to do with the parser and everything to do with a crash somewhere else.   However, without knowing more about the parser, I'd question whether it is hardened against malicious input (which could certainly cause a crash like this).

```
3 ??? 0x00000002 0x0 + 2
```

Stack was undecodable. Ignore.  Meaningless.   Best case;  fallout from compiler optimization.  Worst case;   somebody pooped on the stack and the backtrace mechanism can't figure out what is going on (highly unlikely -- usually, stack poop splatters to the point of preventing a full backtrace).

```
4 MyApp 0x000803f1 msgpack_unpack_next + 112
```

Ooooh... trickzy.   Someone is using C to parse stuff.  And it crashed.   Whatever instruction was 112 bytes from the entry point to the function went *boom*.  But, not really, because it called the signal handler and was handled by that;  which is still a *boom* but the signal handler has effectively destroyed additional forensic evidence.

The "trickzy" comment references that an optimizing compiler against a big pile o' C can end up collapsing frames to the point that the crash could have happened in a function well below this one.

```
5 MyApp 0x0007faeb +[MessagePackParser parseData:] + 74
```

MessagePackParser was parsing when things went horribly wrong.

```
6 MyApp 0x0007f84b -[NSData(NSData_MessagePack) messagePackParse] + 26
7 MyApp 0x000254c3 +[Http get:params:cacheMins:msgPack:complete:] + 146
```

Ahh... yes.... somebody done grabbed some data from HTTP and it was malformed, causing the crash.

Bottom line;  the parser got bogus input and crashed.  There was a signal handler in place that tried to help by creating a backtrace, but -- apparently -- didn't really reveal any more info. A long shot alternative is that the signal was generated somewhere else and this thread was randomly selected to handle it -- if you can consistently recreate this crash, the random-thread-signal case is unlikely.

Unless you have a capture of the input data or can somehow guess how msgpack_unpack_next() might crash, you are out of luck without providing more info.

Comment: “Crash was generated from `+[TFCrashHandler backtrace]`…” Alternatively, the questioner is using a crash-log-reporting framework, TFCrashHandler is a class in the framework, and `+[TFCrashHandler backtrace]` is simply the method that generated this stack trace to send it to the questioner, and is present in its output only because it didn't exclude itself.

Comment: Yah;  exactly.  Sadly, all of which completely obscures the reason why the original crash happened.  Give me registers and I can far better determine the reason of the crash.

Comment: Well, thanks for all your help, its very enlightening. Turns out it was a byte alignment issue in the msgpack_unpack_next function, which was easy enough to fix AFTER i spent forever trying to find where the problem was.

Comment: Oh, dangit!   That unponderable stack frame is a sure fire indication of such an issue, sometimes anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The '???' is something that can't be identified, probably code that was compiled without symbols, but could also be something else.

Comment: Would the hex address on that line "0x0...02" mean that the code jumped into address 2, eg called a function pointer set to '2'?

Comment: It looks like @bbum has addressed the question. When you have a choice between picking his answer and mine, pick his.

Comment: Incomplete. Should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @MaxMacLeod when I wrote this answer I probably didn't have a high enough reputation to comment.

Answer (score -2):

Those are the line numbers in the implementation file.  And the hex is the pointer in memory to the line call.

Comment: Does the '0x00000002' mean that the msgpack_unpack_next function jumped to a function at address '2', eg did an invalid function call somehow?

Comment: @Chris, something like that, this goes back to C programming, not sure exactly how Objective-C does it, but C, when it setup it's memory stack, the first few bits represent a null value, so if the hex value in front is the '0x00000002', then you can assume that it is a null value or undefined.

Comment: The line number don't seem to match up with runnable code. Eg line 74 in the MessagePackParser points to the @end line. Are you sure that's what it is?

Comment: Nope;  not line numbers.  Those are instruction offsets, no symbolication about it.