# iOS: what does those addresses mean in iOS crash log's stack trace?

Tags: ios, debugging, stack-trace, crash-log

This is a line of stack track from my iOS app crash log:

> MyAPPName                     0x001f642e 0xd2000 + 1197102

I know how to symbolicate a crash log, but what does 0x001f642e 0xd2000 + 1197102 mean in every line of stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another form of writing those values is: `0x001f642e = 0xd2000 + 1197102`.

So `0x001f642e` is the actual address of the code being executed, while `0xd2000` is the starting address of the binary where the code is being executed and `1197102` is the offset within the binary.

Comment: Yes, `0xd2000 = 860160 + 1197102 = 2057262 = 0x1F642E`. Use the calculator programmer mode if you want to double check ;)

Comment: You mean 1197102 is decimal?

Comment: Yep, there is no `0x` in front to indicate it being hex.

Answer (score 1):

It's referring to the instruction located at 1197102 bytes from the location 0xd2000.

It's been asked here: [How to read objective-c stack traces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462214/how-to-read-objective-c-stack-traces)

Comment: It didn't say what the 0x001f642e mean, would mind telling me?