# iOS: The + number values in backtraces (in crash logs)

Tags: ios, crash-reports, backtrace

I'm trying to learn how to understand crash logs better and am doing OK so far. I've noticed one part that wasn't explained in [Diagnosing Issues Using Crash Reports and Device Logs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html). This is the + number value at the end of each part of the backtrace.

Here's an example:

```
6   UIKit    0x38bf3e7c -[UIViewController window:willAnimate:duration:] + 704
```

What does the `+ 704` refer to?

Much thanks

Comment: a guess it might be the line number in the source code.

Comment: Good guess, but I don't think it's correct. Line numbers look like: `0x00003dce main (main.m:6)` (the :6 at the end of the filename)

Comment: Those hexadecimal exception numbers in TN2151 are funny.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The number stands for bytes offset from the entry point of the method to the instruction which caused the crash.

Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462214/how-to-read-objective-c-stack-traces) describing how to read and understand stack traces. 
[The tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1) by Ray Wenderlich about dealing with app crashes under iOS in general is also a very good source.

Comment: I am reading the thread you linked and it's making sense so far. The RW link is most welcome too, I appreciate your help.