# What is the crittercism stacktrace meaning?

Tags: objective-c, crittercism

It's the first time I use crittercism and when I take a look to stacktrace there is something like :

> 0x000b24d9 __32-[MenuViewController loadOrders]_block_invoke + 189

What does mean the + 189 ?

I checked, this is not the line number.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other debuggers (i.e. WinDbg) it's the byte offset within that method.

Comment: Tanks ! With you help I found this article : http://www.raywenderlich.com/33669/overview-of-ios-crash-reporting-tools-part-1

Answer (score 1):

The number is the bytes offset from the entry point of the method to the instruction which caused the app to crash. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462214/how-to-read-objective-c-stack-traces) for more info on how to understand crash reports.