# How do I debug this error: CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I am getting an error in my app that I have no idea of how to figure out, has anyone seen this before:

```
#   Binary Image Name   Address Symbol
0   RepZio  0x002bd302  testflight_backtrace
1   RepZio  0x002bc996  TFSignalHandler
2   libsystem_platform.dylib    0x39ce0062  _sigtramp
3   CoreFoundation  0x2edde118  __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__
4   CoreFoundation  0x2ed52256  _CFXNotificationPost
5   Foundation  0x2f737c2c  -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:]
6   Foundation  0x2f73c50a  -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:]
7   UIKit   0x3180b2cc  -[UIApplication _performMemoryWarning]
8   libdispatch.dylib   0x39ba0d06  _dispatch_client_callout
9   libdispatch.dylib   0x39ba9802  _dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$mp
10  libdispatch.dylib   0x39ba773c  _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp
11  CoreFoundation  0x2ede6818  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
12  CoreFoundation  0x2ede50ec  __CFRunLoopRun
13  CoreFoundation  0x2ed4fc26  CFRunLoopRunSpecific
14  CoreFoundation  0x2ed4fa0a  CFRunLoopRunInMode
15  GraphicsServices    0x33a50282  GSEventRunModal
16  UIKit   0x315f3048  UIApplicationMain
17  MyAppName   0x00109afa  main in main.m on Line 15
18  libdyld.dylib   0x39bc5ab6  start
```

Lost on this one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6462751/792677 also `_performMemoryWarning` looks very bad.

Answer (score 17):

Make sure you remove all notification observers before freeing them. This problem occurs when an observer is freed and notification center has still a pointer to that object and tries to notify it. Check that all addObserver have the corresponding removeObserver calls.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's old question, but maybe I will help to someone.

In my case the same crash occurred when `NSTextField` in `NSTableViewCell` was in editing mode and user tried to select value from combobox outside of tableView without finishing editing. And the same `CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_...` crash was on line `[tableView reloadData]`.

So, my way to resolve crash was to put `[self.window makeFirstResponder:nil]` before reloading the table.