# Crash on NotificationCenter addObserver call

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, crash, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm new to this project and Firebase has been added only recently, so I've some issue to figure out the reason of a crash (that I can't reproduce locally).

It's a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS` on `dispatch_call_block_and_release`.
Therefore it should be a memory issue, trying to access to an object that has been already deallocated.

The last traced line is an `addObserver` call of `Notification Center`, and then the call trace continue with several calls but not showing an exact line of code. Since I don't see anything wrong with that observer, I'm wondering: is this line significant? Or it could be that the app is crashing on a different thread so that the call trace is irrelevant?

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000008
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  MyPod                          0x103dafb18 (Missing)
1  MyPod                          0x103daf564 (Missing)
2  MyPod                          0x103daf9fc (Missing)
3  MyApp                          0x103b12ffc (Missing)
4  MyPod                          0x103daf268 (Missing)
5  MyPod                          0x103dae844 (Missing)
6  MyPod                          0x103daef64 (Missing)
7  MyPodClient                    0x103d40fd0 (Missing)
8  MyPodClient                    0x103d3dcb8 (Missing)
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x1a9e38610 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x1a9e39184 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x1a9deb190 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1044
12 CoreFoundation                 0x1aa0ea5e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
13 CoreFoundation                 0x1aa0e55d8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2004
14 CoreFoundation                 0x1aa0e4adc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
15 GraphicsServices               0x1b406a328 GSEventRunModal + 104
16 UIKitCore                      0x1ae1dfae0 UIApplicationMain + 1936
17 MyApp                          0x102e0bce0 main + 21 (PlayerPlugin.swift:21) //-> This is the line in which a func is called, and inside this func observers are added.
```

thanks

ps. I don't know if this helps, but for some crash reports (but not all of them), I get in the KEYS section this line:

```
crash_info_entry_0
CoreUI: deallocating _CUIInternalLinkRendition 7113 /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A6721767-C6DD-43AB-B2E0-094D4CBD12D6/MyApp.app/Assets.car
```

Is this related to assets? However it looks more like a consequence of the crash, rather than a cause.

Comment: Posting the full trace would be helpful.

Comment: Have you seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20746870/4056108)

Comment: @chirag90 Yes, I know how observers work, but the question I'm asking is: since I can't reproduce this crash and the observers implementation looks good, is the problem according to this stack trace the observer or could be something else?

Comment: @chirag90 In the answer you linked, there is a line clearly showing it's related to Post notification. That's not the case in my calls trace.