# Fixing application crash where stacktrace gives none of your own code

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using Crashlytics to report user crashes, somethings I get crash reports with stacktraces that do not make sense to me, the following trace crashes in code I cannot change. Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix these kinds of bugs?

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  ???                            0x00580418 
1  WebCore                        0x370a3b69 WebCore::FontFallbackList::invalidate(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::FontSelector>) + 160
2  WebCore                        0x370a399f WebCore::Font::Font(WebCore::FontPlatformData const&, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::FontSelector>) + 90
3  WebCore                        0x370a393f WebCore::Font::Font(WebCore::FontPlatformData const&, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::FontSelector>) + 10
4  WebKit                         0x379d42ad rendererForFont(__GSFont*) + 240
5  WebKit                         0x379d5edf -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) __web_drawInRect:withFont:ellipsis:alignment:letterSpacing:lineSpacing:includeEmoji:truncationRect:measureOnly:renderedStringOut:drawUnderline:] + 198
6  WebKit                         0x379d5e09 -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) __web_drawInRect:withFont:ellipsis:alignment:letterSpacing:lineSpacing:includeEmoji:truncationRect:measureOnly:renderedStringOut:] + 116
7  WebKit                         0x379d5d85 -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) __web_drawInRect:withFont:ellipsis:alignment:letterSpacing:lineSpacing:includeEmoji:truncationRect:measureOnly:] + 112
8  WebKit                         0x379d5d05 -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) _web_drawInRect:withFont:ellipsis:alignment:lineSpacing:includeEmoji:truncationRect:measureOnly:] + 112
9  WebKit                         0x379d7bbd -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) _web_drawInRect:withFont:ellipsis:alignment:lineSpacing:includeEmoji:truncationRect:] + 92
10 UIKit                          0x32fbe4b3 -[NSString(UIStringDrawing) _drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:lineSpacing:includeEmoji:truncationRect:] + 258
11 UIKit                          0x32fbe39f -[NSString(UIStringDrawing) drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:lineSpacing:includeEmoji:] + 82
12 UIKit                          0x32fbe33b -[NSString(UIStringDrawing) drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:lineSpacing:] + 70
13 UIKit                          0x32fb332d -[UILabel _legacy_drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:] + 2776
14 UIKit                          0x32f76c57 -[UILabel _drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:] + 166
15 UIKit                          0x32f75a23 -[UILabel drawTextInRect:] + 450
16 UIKit                          0x32f7585d -[UILabel drawRect:] + 72
17 UIKit                          0x32f74d1d -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 364
18 QuartzCore                     0x32d23be5 -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 112
19 QuartzCore                     0x32d231b1 CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 1808
20 QuartzCore                     0x32d22915 CA::Layer::display_() + 980
21 QuartzCore                     0x32d1993b CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 202
22 QuartzCore                     0x32d19865 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 24
23 QuartzCore                     0x32d19243 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 238
24 QuartzCore                     0x32d19051 CA::Transaction::commit() + 316
25 UIKit                          0x32f748eb _afterCACommitHandler + 126
26 CoreFoundation                 0x311386cd __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
27 CoreFoundation                 0x311369c1 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 276
28 CoreFoundation                 0x31136d17 __CFRunLoopRun + 742
29 CoreFoundation                 0x310a9ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
30 CoreFoundation                 0x310a9d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
31 GraphicsServices               0x34c712eb GSEventRunModal + 74
32 UIKit                          0x32fbf301 UIApplicationMain + 1120
33 Domino M                       0x0006529f main (main.m:17)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read objective-c stack traces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462214/how-to-read-objective-c-stack-traces)

Comment: do you have a UIWebView loads content right after the app launches ?

Comment: @Basheer_CAD I Do not have UIWebViews in the App, I don't link WebKit or Webcore libraries. I do use RestKit for communication with a backend server

Comment: @Desdenova The duplicate looks a bit different but is interesting though, I know how to read the trace but can't seem to be able to find a good entry point to be able to fix the bug

Comment: you need to symbolicate it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports

Comment: @yeesterbunny Isn't this a symbolicated trace?

Comment: what is the exception/signal type?

Comment: @Kerni EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00580418